# Postgres function with RETURN type as TABLE

Tags: postgresql, set-returning-functions

I have written a Postgres function which returns a TABLE. The problem is when I run the function, the output doesn't look how I expect it to, the 2 columns I define in the TABLE return type are compressed into a single column of type "record". Below you can see the output in PgAdmin4 when I run the function:

[image]

Here is the function, as you can see I am using a for loop to generate the output

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_if_dates_have_log(shopId uuid)
RETURNS table (
    shop_log_date varchar,
    has_log bool
) 
AS $$
Declare
   date_has_log BOOL;
   time_zone_id TEXT;
   current_day_of_month int;
   current_date_str TEXT;
begin
  SELECT data ->> 'time_zone'
  FROM shop
  WHERE id = shopId INTO time_zone_id;

  SELECT date_part('day', current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE time_zone_id) INTO current_day_of_month;

  for counter in 1..current_day_of_month loop
    current_date_str = to_char(current_date, 'YYYY/MM') || '/' || counter;
    SELECT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM shop_log sl
        WHERE
          sl.shop_id = shopId
          AND CAST(((sl.created AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE time_zone_id) AS DATE) = to_date(current_date_str, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
          AND sl.yesterday_output IS NOT NULL
    ) INTO date_has_log;
    raise notice '% %', current_date_str, date_has_log;
    shop_log_date := current_date_str; 
    has_log := date_has_log;
    return next;
  end loop;
end;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you so much, I added FROM into the calling query and it works, I love you.

Comment: what he means is do a `SELECT * FROM function_name()` rather than `SELECT function_name()`